# Facebook language codes table

Tags: php, facebook

If I'm adding like-box or page-plugin so I have to choose the language in which it will be displayed.

But what if I have multilanguage-site system in PHP which remembers only country codes (en,es...). So I probably need a table like this, but with all languages:

```
en => en_US
es => es_ES ...
```

Do you know about some?

Comment: You're using _language_ codes, not _country_ codes. Either way, using `en` will probably prove tricky, what with locales like `en_GB`, `en_CA`, `en_US`, and so on

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization#locales refers to an XML file listing all locales Facebook supports. So you can easily build a list from there yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I created this table from all supported facebok lang-locales then I picked one using `stripos()` and because it few-times picked up wrong code, I re-ordered the array by putting prefered to top of the array.

Maybe it's not the best solution, but it solved my problem.

```
function fb_lang($lang_code){
    $fb_locales = [ 
        'es_ES', 'en_US', 'fr_FR', 'tr_TR', 'sv_SE', // prefered codes are moved to line
        'af_ZA', 'sq_AL', 'ar_AR', 'hy_AM', 'ay_BO', 'az_AZ', 'eu_ES', 'be_BY', 'bn_IN', 'bs_BA', 'bg_BG', 'ca_ES', 'ck_US', 
        'hr_HR', 'cs_CZ', 'da_DK', 'nl_NL', 'nl_BE', 'en_PI', 'en_GB', 'en_UD', 'eo_EO', 'et_EE', 'fo_FO', 'tl_PH', 'fi_FI', 
        'fb_FI', 'fr_CA', 'gl_ES', 'ka_GE', 'de_DE', 'el_GR', 'gn_PY', 'gu_IN', 'he_IL', 'hi_IN', 'hu_HU', 'is_IS', 'id_ID', 
        'ga_IE', 'it_IT', 'ja_JP', 'jv_ID', 'kn_IN', 'kk_KZ', 'km_KH', 'tl_ST', 'ko_KR', 'ku_TR', 'la_VA', 'lv_LV', 'fb_LT', 'li_NL', 
        'lt_LT', 'mk_MK', 'mg_MG', 'ms_MY', 'ml_IN', 'mt_MT', 'mr_IN', 'mn_MN', 'ne_NP', 'se_NO', 'nb_NO', 'nn_NO', 'ps_AF', 'fa_IR', 
        'pl_PL', 'pt_BR', 'pt_PT', 'pa_IN', 'qu_PE', 'ro_RO', 'rm_CH', 'ru_RU', 'sa_IN', 'sr_RS', 'zh_CN', 'sk_SK', 'sl_SI', 'so_SO', 
        'es_LA', 'es_CL', 'es_CO', 'es_MX', 'es_VE', 'sw_KE', 'sy_SY', 'tg_TJ', 'ta_IN', 'tt_RU', 'te_IN', 'th_TH', 
        'zh_HK', 'zh_TW', 'uk_UA', 'ur_PK', 'uz_UZ', 'vi_VN', 'cy_GB', 'xh_ZA', 'yi_DE', 'zu_ZA'
    ];
    foreach($fb_locales as $fbl){
        if(stripos($fbl,$lang_code)!==false){
            return $fbl;
        }
    }
    trigger_error('Fb_lang() couldn\'t find equvalent for language code "'.$lang_code.'"');
    return 'en_US';
}
```

Hope it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is using country codes, but this codes are a bit more specific so they are mostly called **Locale ID** (language and country code).

You could just grab the XML from facebook with all locale ids used by them:

```
<locale>
  <englishName>English (UK)</englishName>
    <codes>
      <code>
        <standard>
          <name>FB</name>
          <representation>en_GB</representation>
        </standard>
      </code>
   </codes>
</locale>
```

You can find the whole file here (https://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml)

**BUT:**
The Problem here is, that you cannot refer from `en` to `en_US` or `en_GB`. So the mapping from 2 to 4 letters won't work. You need to have a table with the language and country code like `en_US`.

Most modern browser send an "accept language" header, but **beware** It's not 100% reliable and it's just the primary language of the users browser and not really the country code.

try: `var_dump( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] );`
to get: `fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4`

You can also try to use an API i.e. http://www.hostip.info/

An example would be:

```
$theFirstPart = "en";// you said you already got this
$userIP = "12.215.42.19";// from $_SERVER var

$languageCode = "en_US";// your standard

//you should use curl for this
// and it's really slow, so please cache this for at least a day or two ;)
$content = file_get_contents( "http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?ip=$userIP" );
if( $content ) {
    $json = json_decode( $content );
    if( $json && isset( $json->country_code ) ) {
        // before you assign the value, you should check if it's in the facebook xml
        $languageCode = $theFirstPart.'_'.$json->country_code;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump( $languageCode );
}
```